# Check N number of columns where same condition met between consecutive dates and return number and ID of columns for each group

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by

```
          Date   MAC     SENS_1   SENS_2     SENS_3      SENS_4     SENS_N
0   2023-06-08  MAC1  79.608346  64.2030  66.181849  149.590573  12.135441
1   2023-06-09  MAC1  80.655564  64.6430  67.636943  109.034809  12.278676
2   2023-06-08  MAC2   5.323341   4.7814  57.231430   51.422297   0.494853
3   2023-06-09  MAC2   5.375561   4.7788  63.701169   88.638871   0.471265
4   2023-06-08  MAC3   3.221366   3.0242  61.071023  113.812544   0.251471
5   2023-06-09  MAC3   3.277577   3.0300  67.280632  133.127433   0.274765
6   2023-06-08  MAC4   3.029806   2.6720  63.310941   72.074345   0.393294
7   2023-06-09  MAC4   3.129871   2.6850  72.727142  100.133454   0.408941
8   2023-06-08  MAC5  18.987204  18.1676  57.660920   98.760819   1.219735
9   2023-06-09  MAC5  19.158136  18.1766  61.598102   93.546477   1.270471
10  2023-06-08  MACN  38.190817  35.2416  68.589171  160.597307   2.531353
11  2023-06-09  MACN  38.393878  34.3196  67.710298  139.854140   2.675000
```

For this dataframe I would like to know how many **SENSORS** for each **MACHINE** creating a **HIGH-LOW** situation for the latest date.

**SENS_1** value of **MAC1** for today (2023-06-09) is greater than yesterday's (2023-06-08) value. Also it's the same for **SENS_2**, **SENS_3** and **SENS_N**

So what I need to return is a list(df) of MACHINEs with the name and numbers of SENSORS that meet the condition:

```
| MACHINE | SENSORS | N. of SENSORS |
|:---- |:------:| -----:|
| MAC1  | SENS_1,SENS_2,SENS_3,SENS_N    | 4 |
| MAC2  | SENS_1,SENS_3,SENS_4    | 3 |
| MAC3  | SENS_1,SENS_2,SENS_3,SENS_4,SENS_N    | 5 |
| MAC4 | SENS_1,SENS_2,SENS_3,SENS_4,SENS_N    | 5 |
| MAC5 | SENS_1,SENS_2,SENS_3,SENS_N    | 4 |
| MACN | SENS_1,SENS_N    | 2 |
```

I can use:

```
high_lows = df.loc[(df['MAC1'] == df['MAC1'].shift(-1)) & (df['SENS_5'] < df['SENS_5'].shift(-1)) ,'MAC1']
```

to identify SENSORS with high-lows one by one.
However there are almost **500 machines and 150 sensors**.

So I think I need to iterate over columns by selecting SENSORS after MAC column:

```
df.iloc[:,2:]
```

and check for the condition.

*However this function will run every 2000ms(2secs) so it has to be done with the fastest way possible.*

What is the most efficient way of iterating over N columns for N groups and extract groups that match the condition?

*Example data with NaNs:*

```
           Date    MAC     SENS_1   SENS_2     SENS_3      SENS_4     SENS_5
82   2023-06-08  MAC41  79.608346      NaN  66.181849  149.590573  12.135441
83   2023-06-09  MAC41  80.655564      NaN  67.636943  109.034809  12.278676
```

Comment: You have only two dates?

Comment: Exactly. Only today's date and yesterday.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
def count(df):
    m = df.iloc[:, 2:].diff().fillna(True).gt(0).all(axis=0)
    return pd.Series({'Sensors': ', '.join(m.index[m]), 'Count': m.sum()})

out = df.groupby('MAC', as_index=False).apply(count)
```

Output:

```
>>> out
    MAC                                 Sensors  Count
0  MAC1          SENS_1, SENS_2, SENS_3, SENS_N      4
1  MAC2                  SENS_1, SENS_3, SENS_4      3
2  MAC3  SENS_1, SENS_2, SENS_3, SENS_4, SENS_N      5
3  MAC4  SENS_1, SENS_2, SENS_3, SENS_4, SENS_N      5
4  MAC5          SENS_1, SENS_2, SENS_3, SENS_N      4
5  MACN                          SENS_1, SENS_N      2
```

Alternative (as you have only today and yesterday rows per machine):

```
def count(df):
    m = df.iloc[1, 2:] - df.iloc[0, 2:] > 0
    return pd.Series({'Sensors': ', '.join(m.index[m]), 'Count': m.sum()})

out = df.groupby('MAC', as_index=False).apply(count)
```

Comment: Excellent. It only took 0.5secs

Comment: However there is a slight issue. This also counts the sensors that show NaN values (I had no idea) as HLs and add them to the final list.

Comment: What should be the behavior in this case?

Comment: Try: `df.fillna(-np.inf).groupby('MAC', as_index=False).apply(count)`

Comment: It doesn't work. For instance MAC14 shows NaN values for the SEN_14 for both dates.

Comment: Can you share your data?

Comment: I added sample data to the main question. Sensors don't send signals sometimes so thats why those values are NaN. Current solution also count these NaNs.

Comment: @drnsrc. I added an alternative for this use case. Let me know if it works (assuming only 2 rows per machine)

Answer (score 1):

```
columns = df.columns[2:]

diffs = (
   df.groupby('MAC', sort=False)[columns]
     .diff().dropna().gt(0)     
     .where(lambda df: ~df, columns.to_series(), axis=1) # Replace `True` with column name
     .replace(False, float('nan'))
)   

count = diffs.count(axis=1)
str_concat = diffs.agg(lambda cols: ','.join(cols.dropna()), axis=1)

out = df.loc[count.index, ['MAC']]

out['SENSORS'] = str_concat
out['N. OF SENSORS'] = count
```

```
     MAC                             SENSORS  N. OF SENSORS
1   MAC1         SENS_1,SENS_2,SENS_3,SENS_N              4
3   MAC2                SENS_1,SENS_3,SENS_4              3
5   MAC3  SENS_1,SENS_2,SENS_3,SENS_4,SENS_N              5
7   MAC4  SENS_1,SENS_2,SENS_3,SENS_4,SENS_N              5
9   MAC5         SENS_1,SENS_2,SENS_3,SENS_N              4
11  MACN                       SENS_1,SENS_N              2
```